# sql select condition more than another condition from same column

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have table with Emp_Period and Emp_Salaries. I need to select data with salaries greater than another salary with different condition.

Select statement

```
select * 
from Employee 
where Emp_Period >96 
  and Emp_Salary < (select Emp_Salary 
                    from Employee 
                    where Emp_Period <24)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a `max` around 'Emp_Salary' in the condition? Some data would help too.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please also read about how questions are to be asked and about [a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How I can get data from those condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful.  I would tend to use aggregation for this logic:

```
e.Emp_Salary > (select max(e2.Emp_Salary)
                from Employee e2
                where e2.Emp_Period < 24
               )
```

(Note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.)

The subquery will return a `NULL` value if no employees meet the condition.  SQL has a similar mechanism using *`ALL`*:

```
e.Emp_Salary > all (select e2.Emp_Salary
                    from Employee e2
                    where e2.Emp_Period < 24
                   )
```

`ANY` is not appropriate here.

This version and the aggregate version are subtly different.  The aggregation version is `false` if no employees match the condition in the subquery.  The `ALL` version is `true` if no employees match the condition.  It is unclear which version the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Less Than or Greater Than Operator can't check for multiple records. but here you can perform Advanced Operators like `in ()`

**Demo**

```
select * 
    from Employee 
    where Emp_Period >96 
      and Emp_Salary in (select Emp_Salary 
                        from Employee 
                        where Emp_Period <24)
```

Comment: "*Less Than or Greater Than Operator can't check for multiple records*" not exactly true. You can use them, but you need to combine the operator with `all` or `any` , e.g. `where emp_salary > all (select ...)`

Comment: I ever use this method but didn't work. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Ah Thanks, I need 'any' to answer the question. Here my code

```
select * 
from Employee 
where Emp_Period >96 
  and Emp_Salary <any (select Emp_Salary 
                    from Employee 
                    where Emp_Period <24 )
```